# Suppress incoming message popups from a specific account in Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I recently added a second account to my Microsoft Outlook 2010. This account has about 74k mails and there are steady new status updates. Are there any settings to suppress the popups?

Comment: This might help, http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-new-message-alert-pop-up-window-HA010355032.aspx

Comment: Is that possible that I can turn of the message alert pop up for only one account? I know that I can specify a rule that all mails from Inbox can be put in a subfolder (then also no alert appear).